# How to print a Google form?

Tags: google-drive, google-forms, printing

I made a neat questionnaire Form in Google Docs. I want to print it for hand outs to my testers IRL.

But I cannot find a way to print it to paper, or even export it to PDF. There are not many buttons to choose from, and it was hard to find the answer googling.

Printing the web page from the browser obviously prints a web form with typical controls like resizable "text paragraph" answer boxes,  radio buttons, and even a submit button. This is what I got right now, but I am looking for a better option.

Is it possible to make a Google Document Form print friendly? **If not, is there any other free web application that lets me do this?**

Comment: No. Google Forms are meant to be filled out online. It's not a paper form builder. In fact, the design guidelines for paper forms are very much different.

Comment: To me, this feels like a lacking feature. If so, and if there is no workaround, then naming a web app that cannot only build and also print forms, would be the answer.

Comment: It's not a lacking feature: ***design guidelines for digital & print forms are very different***. If you want a printable form, open any text editor and create it there.

Comment: To me it is. Yes, design differ, but I think this design is translatable to paper. Questionnaires on paper does not differ that much in concept. I just hope that someone made a translation already. :)

Comment: I know my answer does not point to a free service, but it seems to be the only service on the web that offers this and therefore, I believe it is worthy of being checked off as a successful answer.  What do you think?  I am referencing: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/35870/29504

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally...they now support printing it out.

https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleDrive/posts/ZSWMyZKC22t

Comment: Welp, there goes my little side biz. At least I beat them to it by a year or so: http://vivwebsolutions.com/tools/google-paper-forms/

Answer (score 4):

You can do easily from your Internet Browser

Go to **File** *menu* then choose **Print**

try it using the following example : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/viewform?formkey=dFBSU1ZiYzZ6MUpGeE90X0lGTl8xQXc6MA

Check the below images

***Chrome***

[image: Google Chrome]

***IE***

[image: Internet Explorer]

Comment: Thanks, I did this of course, but it obviously prints a web form with typical controls like resizable "text paragraph" answer boxes,  radiobuttons, and even a submit button. :) I'll add this to my question.

Comment: This is the only way to print the form side, unfortunately. There aren't any options in the form creation side to print the form.

Answer (score 4):

I agree 100% with the OP that, while design specs are slightly different for print versus paper forms, they certainly are translatable.

I was frustrated with the same problem, so I created a small web app called [Google Paper Forms](http://vivwebsolutions.com/tools/google-paper-forms/) that will do exactly what you are looking to do: translate your Google Form to a printable, paper-ready PDF file.  It intelligently expands multi-select questions and formats text-based answer fields to look appropriate on paper.

There is a small fee for final translation, but you can sample how it will look for free.  I hope this solves your problem, and I welcome any feedback about the tool.  Here is the URL: http://vivwebsolutions.com/tools/google-paper-forms/

Answer (score 0):

Send it to one of Readit Extensions for better layout and form stripping.

Example: http://www.readability.com/

Using Space Cracker's image, this is how it looks in Readability

[image: Readability Layout]

Though you still get back to the original problem of printing.

On a Mac this is how the print layout looks,

[image: First line shifted]

Answer (score 0):

You could save the whole page as an image but then you would have to manually cut it into separate pages again. Depending on whether it stays on the whole page or not you can use an extension

For example using [Screen Capture (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg)

For forms with radio buttons you can mix and match with [setup](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/25466/40)

[image: Screenshot image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to print a form in the latest downgrade of Google Docs.

- Firstly, open the form. There should be a button that says *Go to live form* on the main toolbar.
- Click on it, then copy the URL.
- Now log out of your Google account and paste the URL into the address bar or your browser.
- This will bring you to the same page as the "Go to live form" button, but now it doesn't have a pesky "Click here to edit form" tag that shows up when you print.
- Simply print from your browser's File menu, use Print Preview if you wish to crop out the Submit button.

Yes, I know this is an old question, but I think this info should be out there, as Google has sadly banished the Print button forever.

Comment: I followed the steps but I still get the same result, with the Submit button, links, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all the form in the Google form editor (CtrlA) then paste it into a new Word document. It takes some time to paste a long form so be patient.

In Word, it formats quite neatly for printing and includes the drop down box list of responses etc. which can be viewed in Word.